# How to set LangOptions for AST Matcher (bool vs _Bool)

Tags: types, boolean, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, matcher

Is there any way how to setup LangOptions for AST matcher? We have following matcher:

```cpp
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory OptionCategory("options");

class CMatcherCallback : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback
{
public:
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result) override
    {
        if (const CXXMethodDecl* method = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXMethodDecl>("id"))
        {
            method->dumpColor();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    tooling::CommonOptionsParser optionsParser(argc, argv, OptionCategory);
    tooling::ClangTool tool(optionsParser.getCompilations(),
                            optionsParser.getSourcePathList());

    CMatcherCallback callback;
    MatchFinder finder;
    finder.addMatcher(cxxMethodDecl(
                          hasName("Method"),
                          hasParameter(0, parmVarDecl(hasType(asString("bool")))))
                          .bind("id"),
                      &callback);
    int ret = tool.run(tooling::newFrontendActionFactory(&finder).get());

    return ret;
}
```

It doesn't match this method:

```cpp
class CTest
{
  void Method(bool);
};
```

It does match when we change type from `hasParameter(0, parmVarDecl(hasType(asString("bool")))))`
to `_Bool`. So it seems matcher is in C instead of C++ mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering the actual question

This answer won't solve the original problem (explanation below), but solves the problem stated in the question. It might be useful if someone will search for a way to set the options.

```cpp
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory OptionCategory("options");

class CMatcherCallback : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public:
  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &result) override {
    if (const CXXMethodDecl *method =
            result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXMethodDecl>("id")) {
      method->dumpColor();
    }
  }
};

class FinderFrontendAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
  FinderFrontendAction() {
    Finder.addMatcher(
        cxxMethodDecl(hasName("Method"),
                      hasParameter(0, parmVarDecl(hasType(asString("bool")))))
            .bind("id"),
        &Callback);
  }

  std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer>
  CreateASTConsumer(clang::CompilerInstance &CI, llvm::StringRef) override {
    auto &LO = CI.getLangOpts();
    LO.CPlusPlus = true;
    LO.Bool = true; // this is the actual option you are interested in
    return Finder.newASTConsumer();
  }

private:
  MatchFinder Finder;
  CMatcherCallback Callback;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  tooling::CommonOptionsParser optionsParser(argc, argv, OptionCategory);
  tooling::ClangTool tool(optionsParser.getCompilations(),
                          optionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  int ret =
      tool.run(tooling::newFrontendActionFactory<FinderFrontendAction>().get());

  return ret;
}
```

### Why it won't change the outcome

Clang understands that this is a C++ code and that it has `bool` type on its own. So this code literally changes nothing. You can see that when you print the AST, it actually prints `bool`.

### So where does _Bool come from

This is a problem of how `asString` matcher is implemented. It uses [QualType::getAsString()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html#ab6d17bbf405e8fdb04a67518be3b46d1) method (without parameters). Parametrized version of this function accepts [PrintingPolicy](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1PrintingPolicy.html), which defines how different types should be printed out.

`LangOpts` define the way certain types are printed because `PrintingPolicy` is constructed from it, but not when you call `QualType::getAsString` without a printing policy. It uses default `LangOpts` constructor and `bool` becomes `"_Bool"`.

### Suggested solution

Just deal with it and use `"_Bool"`. Otherwise you can implement your own matcher that combats this shortcoming.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: While this is a good answer because it explains what's going on, I (kinda sorta) disagree with switching to `_Bool`, and I prefer the OP's answer (which you briefly suggested). There's nothing preventing  `QualType::getAsString()` of the next Clang version from returning `bool` rather than `_Bool`. With the printing options however, we are no longer prone to this problem. True, the AST in general is probably prone to some changes between Clang versions, but the less we depend on version changes the better IMHO!

Answer (score 2):

Custom AST matcher is simple after all, thanks to Valeriy for pointing it out.

```cpp
namespace my_matchers
{
    AST_MATCHER_P2(QualType, asString, std::string, Name, PrintingPolicy, PP)
    {
        return Name == Node.getAsString(PP);
    }
}

...
PrintingPolicy printingPolicy(LangOptions{});
printingPolicy.Bool = 1;
...
hasParameter(0, parmVarDecl(hasType(my_matchers::asString("bool", printingPolicy))))
```